# Cloudera hadoop Connector in Tableau

Tags: hadoop, tableau-api, cloudera

I am trying to connect tableau with cloudera hadoop, however i am not able  to connect. Getting below error: The below one is when using `UserName and Password`

[image]

When tried with `No Authentication` get below error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to solve the above problem. Could be useful for someone, so updating the answer here:

Hadoop server installed was `kerberos` enabled server. So we installed `MIT Kerberos` on tableau server and enabled token.

Then connected tableau with `kerberos authentication` for cloudera hadoop and then it was working.